# Emacs shell/term - unlock cursor from madly scrolling output

Tags: haskell, emacs

I would like to temporarily decouple the cursor from the terminal output in emacs. In an eclipse console there's a button for this, so you can page up and see previous output without the latest line of output grabbing the cursor back.

Does emacs allow you to do this? Is there some variable or command?

**Update:** I'm actually using plugins that run a GHCi (Haskell) REPL in a terminal window. I guess I assumed they would have built the REPL on top of the terminal or eshell in out-of-box Emacs. But the `term-line-mode` command @Jack pointed out is for some reason not available in the GHCi REPL. So I guess this just became a Haskell-specific question...

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `term-line-mode`. By default it should be <kbd>C-c C-j</kbd>, so you can toggle it on and off.

Comment: Thanks @Jack. Great answer. I updated the Question to explain that this is actually a Haskell REPL provided by a plugin. I would have expected it to have the features of a standard shell, but apparently not.